# How to multiselect in a ListView using Shift + up/down Keys

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls

I had WPF ListView in my xaml file and having issue to multiselect rows using Shift + Up/Down keys.

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the [`SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx) is set appropriately, like `Extended`.

Comment: yes, I did but still cannot make multiselection by using shift + up/down keys. Thanks

Comment: @Jing: Did you override something in the ListView or did you disable controls? You should be able to select like this by default (you can try that in a clean project).

Comment: @Jing Are you using `MVVM` pattern? Seems like you've blocked selection.

Comment: Thanks for help. It works now. I overrided the key handling so it stops the selection.